# Is there any type of cyber attack for which the geographical distance between the attacker and the target matters?

Tags: attacks, cyber-warfare

### Context

I cannot remember the source, but it was most likely within the comments box for a clip about cyberattacks happening after the Russian invasion of Ukraine. It was something along the lines:

- comment: party X moved its hackers closer to the target Y
- reply: cyber attacks do not work as the normal attacks do, it does not matter how far the attacker is from its target

This discussion clearly lacks accuracy, so I will try to clarify as much as I can:

- by hackers, I am interested actually in machines involved in the attack (e.g. infected machines part of DDos)
- by closer I understand geographical distance, although I think the network round-trip is what actually matters here

### Question

This made me wonder if the reply is entirely accurate. I think that for most types of attacks, the geographical distance is not that important, but I am wondering **if there is any type of attack where being closer makes a difference.**

I know that for [some specific operations](https://www.npr.org/2014/04/01/297686724/on-a-rigged-wall-street-milliseconds-make-all-the-difference?t=1652284885237) distance between the systems is of great importance, that's why I imagine that for some types of attacks this might matter.

Comment: Are attacks against wireless devices not classified as cyber attacks?

Comment: @user Yes, this type of attack is a good match. However, I am not sure about its usage in a cyber warfare.

Comment: There are a whole class of cyber attacks that require physical access to the device being attacked - for example, the infamous [evil maid attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159173/what-exactly-is-an-evil-maid-attack).

Comment: timing attacks work better the fewer hops they make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are narrowing your scope down to attacks over the Internet, but the cyberspace is not that limited. Take a look at the definitions from, e.g., [NIST SP 800-39](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-39.pdf):

> Cyber Attack
>
> An attack, via cyberspace, targeting an enterprise’s use of cyberspace
> for the purpose of disrupting, disabling, destroying, or maliciously
> controlling a computing environment/infrastructure; or destroying the
> integrity of the data or stealing controlled information.
>
> Cyberspace
>
> A global domain within the information environment consisting of the
> interdependent network of information systems infrastructures
> including the Internet, telecommunications networks, computer systems,
> and embedded processors and controllers.

In this wider scope, geographical distance does have a meaning.

- Attacks over wireless networks.
- Radio jamming / radio interference attacks.
- Attacks using access to physical devices or cables. Evil maid attacks, wiretapping, fiber tapping. Or sabotage...

  - Will Oremus (2014): [The Global Internet Is Being Attacked by Sharks, Google Confirms](https://slate.com/technology/2014/08/shark-attacks-threaten-google-s-undersea-internet-cables-video.html)

    > [image: Slate: Screenshot / YouTube]
    >
    > *Sharks’ attraction to undersea fiber-optic cables has been well-documented over the years.*
- Networkless attacks delivered via, e.g., USB sticks or other removable media, like in the delivery of the Stuxnet.

  - Catalin Cimpanu (2018): [Here's a List of 29 Different Types of USB Attacks](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/heres-a-list-of-29-different-types-of-usb-attacks/).
  - Aleksandr Matrosov; Eugene Rodionov; David Harley & Juraj Malcho (2012): [Stuxnet Under the Microscope, Revision 1.31](https://www.welivesecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Stuxnet_Under_the_Microscope.pdf), PDF, page 10.